# Couldn't understand div elements

Tags: html, css

I have two `div` elements and `nav > nav_1`. I am expecting to see **500x500** black color background and **50x50** blue color area on the top left but instead of showing me only **500x500** black area. how could i fix it?

```css
.nav {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: black;
}
.nav.nav1 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="nav_1">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Change `.nav.nav1`  to `.nav .nav_1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in your CSS, you were using `.nav1` instead of `.nav_1`. Secondly put a space between `.nav` and `.nav_1`. Try this:

```
 .nav .nav_1{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:blue; 
  }
```

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hj1wL4mh/1/) for the same.

**EDIT:**
For getting a margin-top of 50px, try this:

```
.nav{
 height:500px;
width:500px;
background-color:black;
position:fixed; /* fix position of .nav div */
}

.nav  .nav_1{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    background-color:blue; 
   margin-top: 50px ; /* put margin-top to 50px */
}
```

Here is the [Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e9kn88at/) for the same.

Comment: @Alorika actually my main question is different but made a little mistake like dont putting space between nav and nav_1 so i ask that first...my main quesiton is i add a margin-top:50px; to .nav_1 and that 50px moving the .nav too.....i was expecting to see only .nav_1 will move....because nav_1 element of nav it means nav include nav_1 right ?

Comment: What do you want to do? Put a `margin-top` of `50px` to `.nav_1` ?

Comment: @Alorika yes for .nav_1

Comment: @alireza: he asked another question in the comment. Wat abt that?

Comment: It depends on other reviewers. If they accept to close the question, then it will be closed .

Comment: @alirezasafian upvoted, closed questions with upvoted, accepted answers are not deleted.